# Two definitions of very ample line bundle and a property its tensor powers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In literature there are two slightly different definitions of a very ample line bundle: weak and strong.

According to the weak definition (see e.g. Hartshorne's book) a line bundle $L$ over $X$ is called very ample if there is a closed imbedding $f\colon X\to \mathbb{P}^N$ such that $L\simeq f^*\mathcal{O}(1)$.

The strong definition is as follows. Assume that $L$ is generated by  the space $V=\Gamma(X,L)$ of global sections.
Consider the map
$g\colon X\to \mathbb{P}(V^*)$ given by $$x\mapsto (Ker[V\to L_x])^\perp,$$
where $V\to L_x$ is the restriction map of a global section to the fiver over $x$.
Then $g$ is a closed imbedding.

Clearly the strong definition implies the weak one.

**Let $L\to X$ be a very ample bundle in the strong sense. Is it true that for any $k>0$ the line bundle $L^{\otimes k}$ is also very ample in the strong sense?**

Remark. It is easy to see that if in the previous question one replaces 'strong sense' by 'weak sense' then the answer is positive.

Comment: These 'weak' and 'strong' notions are equivalent (at least when the base is a field); see for instance \[Tag [01VR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VR)(1)$\Leftrightarrow$(4)\].

Comment: Oh, you are right. This answers my question. Thank you.